Find the value of $\sum_{r=0}^{10}\binom{20+r}{20} \binom{20-r}{10}$
Find the value of $$\sum_{r=0}^{10}\binom{20+r}{20} \binom{20-r}{10}$$
I tried a lot but couldn't come up with answer. It looks like an extended version of the Hockey Stick identity.
Something like this is given here but I could not understand it
Summation of double choose functions. Can there be a more elementary approach
